# Vue $emit not getting executed in finally()

Tags: vue.js, promise, fetch

In `LoginForm.vue` I have this function:

```js
login() {
    event.preventDefault();
    let data = {
        email : this.email,
        password : this.password
    };
    if(this.remember)
        data['remember'] = 'on';
    this.$emit('toggle-load-overlay', true);
    fetch(this.loginRoute, {
        method : 'POST',
        body : JSON.stringify(data),
        headers : {
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : this.csrf,
        },
    })
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(data => {
    if(!data['success'])
        this.errors = data['errors'];
    else {
        this.csrf = data['csrf'];
        this.$emit('loggedin', data['user']);
        this.$emit('update-token', data['csrf']);
    }
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
    .finally(() => {
         this.$emit('toggle-load-overlay', false);
    });
}
```

Before fetching, I put a load overlay on the screen, by emitting an event to my `AuthComponent.vue` - `this.$emit('toggle-load-overlay', true);`

In `AuthComponent.vue` the event handler looks like this:

```js
toggleLoadOverlay(displayOverlay) {
    this.isLoading = displayOverlay;
}
```

The first emit gets executed and overlay is put on. Then, in `finally()` I try to emit the same event again in order to hide the overlay. But it does not get executed. I debugged it, it gets in the `finally()`, but emit does not get executed.

Also, I've observed what is happening inside `$emit` method:

```js
Vue.prototype.$emit = function (event) {
    var vm = this;
    {
        var lowerCaseEvent = event.toLowerCase();
        if (lowerCaseEvent !== event && vm._events[lowerCaseEvent]) {
        tip(
            "Event \"" + lowerCaseEvent + "\" is emitted in component " +
            (formatComponentName(vm)) + " but the handler is registered for \"" + event + "\". " +
            "Note that HTML attributes are case-insensitive and you cannot use " +
            "v-on to listen to camelCase events when using in-DOM templates. " +
            "You should probably use \"" + (hyphenate(event)) + "\" instead of \"" + event + "\"."
            );
        }
    }
    var cbs = vm._events[event];
    if (cbs) {
        cbs = cbs.length > 1 ? toArray(cbs) : cbs;
        var args = toArray(arguments, 1);
        var info = "event handler for \"" + event + "\"";
        for (var i = 0, l = cbs.length; i < l; i++) {
        invokeWithErrorHandling(cbs[i], vm, args, vm, info);
        }
    }
    return vm
};
```

I've noticed one difference between these two emits. In this line `var cbs = vm._events[event]` the `vm._events` is not empty on first emit (it has the event `toggleLoadOverlay`), while on the second emit, it is empty.

Another observation, is that second emit works inside the final `then()` statement. So for now I will put it there, as well as in the `catch()`. But the intention of `finally()` was that the code wouldn't have to be duplicated.

1. Why `this.$emit('toggle-load-overlay', false)` does not work in the `finally()` in my current code?
2. Why does it work in then/catch?
3. Is there a way to make it so that it would work in `finally()` as well?

Comment: Could you create a [mcve] reproducing the bug? Use codesandbox.io if you need a multi-file node based environment or a basic [SO] snippet if you can wrap it up with using umd imports (cdn scripts).Are you sure your implementation of Promise has `finally()` (not all do).

Answer (score -1):

It's working, can you check your parent component if event is being handled

please not: this is a general solution to test if $emit works in finally.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <div v-if="loading">Loading...</div>
        <test @set-loader="setLoader"></test>
    </div>

    <script>
        Vue.component('test',{
            template:'<div>Hi</div>',
            mounted:function(){
                fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(json => console.log(json))
                .finally(() => {
                    console.log('child finally');
                    this.$emit('set-loader', false);
                });

            }
        });
        new Vue({
            el:'#app',
            data:{
                loading:true
            },
            methods:{
                setLoader: function(value){
                    console.log('parent event');
                    console.log(value);
                    this.loading = value;
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you downvote, you need to tell the reason instead of doing to silently.